# php why str_replace not working with html

Tags: php

why here str_replace not working

```
<?php
$str= '<div class=\"droppable\" ondrop=\"drop(event)\" ondragover=\"allowDrop(event)\"></div>';
echo str_replace('\"','"', $str);
```

i want to use str_replace with HTML tag.

Comment: Please define "not working". I tested your code and to me it seems to work. So tell us what output you expect and what output you actually get.

Comment: the output of your code is `<div class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>` what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

As I get you want to remove the `\`s to get proper HTML.

Better way should be -

```
stripslashes('<div class=\"droppable\" ondrop=\"drop(event)\" ondragover=\"allowDrop(event)\"></div>');
```

**Output**

```
<div class="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

[stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: `'\"'` is literally a "slash-double-quote". It will be escaped in `"\""`

Comment: sss.. mistaken the quotes. :)